# Каким образом построить домен freeipa с клиентами на AstraLinux, Ubuntu, Debian и CentOS?

Tags: astra-linux, domain, freeipa

**Задача**: организовать централизованное управление учётными записями/публичными ключами, группами и настройками для большого парка серверов(700+) на AstraLinux, Ubuntu, Debian и CentOS.
В качестве контроллера домена выбран FreeIPA. В ходе тестов выявлено, что FreeIPA для AstraLinux имеет отдельную реализацию (пакеты astra-freeipa-server и astra-freeipa-client), которые несовместимы с общедоступными freeipa-server и freeipa-client. freeipa-client при попытке подключения к домену astra-freeipa ругается на модуль admintools.py, astra-freeipa-client при подключении к домену freeipa-server ведёт себя похожим образом. Несовместимость очевидна.

**Возможное решение**: Настроить доверительные отношения между серверами astra-freeipa-server и freeipa-server.

**Вопрос**: Возможно ли это в принципе? Будет ли это так работать? Если это так не работает, то какие есть практики для решение этой задачи?

Comment: поставь клиент из дебиана в астру.

Comment: Да установка обычного freeipa-client в астре работает норм. Спасибо.